# Integral mean value theorem Proof

Tags: integration

I have to the following question :-

f,g ∈ C [a,b], h ∈ R [a,b]

h(x) $\geq$ m , where m > 0

Use the integral mean value theorem to prove that if

$$\int_a^bf(x)h(x)dx = \int_a^bg(x)h(x)dx$$

the there exisits a c ∈ [a,b] such that f(c) = g(c)

Below shows my attempt at this question

This implies h(x) $\geq$ 0 , for all x ∈ [a,b]

There exists c ∈ [a,b] s.t

$$\int^b_af(x)h(x) = f(c)\int^b_ah(x)dx$$

Proof - $$m = inf f(x) x ∈ [a,b]$$
        $$M = sup f(x) x ∈ [a,b]$$

$$m \leq f(x) \leq M, \forall x ∈ [a,b] $$

$$mh(x) \leq f(x)h(x) \leq Mh(x)$$
$$m\int^b_ah(x)dx \leq \int^b_af(x)h(x) \leq M \int^b_ah(x)dx$$
$$since \int^b_ah(x)dx \not=0$$

$$m \leq \frac{\int^b_af(x)h(x)dx}{\int^b_ah(x)dx} \leq M$$

$$m \leq \overline{f} \leq M$$

$$where \overline{f} = \frac{\int^b_af(x)h(x)dx}{\int^b_ah(x)dx}$$

$$since f ∈ C [a,b], by EVT $$

There exists p,q ∈  [a,b]  m = f(p) and M = f(q)

$$f(p) \leq \overline{f} \leq f(q)$$

By the Intermediate value theorem (IMT) since f ∈  C[a,b] and $\overline{f}$

$$ f(p) \leq \overline{f} \leq f(q)$$

There exists a c ∈ [a,b] s.t.

$$f(c) = \overline{f} = \frac{\int^b_af(x)h(x)}{\int^b_ah(x)}$$

Therefore$$ c ∈  [a,b] s.t. f(c) = \overline{f} = \frac{\int^b_af(x)h(x)}{\int^b_ah(x)}$$

and for g(c) it follows the same way

Therefore$$ c ∈  [a,b] s.t. g(c) = \overline{f} = \frac{\int^b_ag(x)h(x)}{\int^b_ah(x)}$$

$$Hence  for f(c) = g(c) $$

$$\frac{\int^b_af(x)h(x)dx}{\int^b_ah(x)dx}= \frac{\int^b_ag(x)h(x)dx}{\int^b_ah(x)dx}$$

can anyone tell me if this is correct and if not what should I do to prove the previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given condition is equivalent with

$$(I)\;\;\;\int_a^b(f(x)-g(x))h(x)\,dx=0$$

Now, $\;h(x)\ge m>0\;$ and $\;p(x):=f(x)-g(x)\;$ is a continuous function. If $\;p\;$ doesn't change sign on $\;[a,b]\;$, then $\;p(x)h(x)\;$ is all the time positive or all the time negative, which cannot be by $\;(I)\;$ above. Thus, $\;p(x)\;$ changes sign on $\;[a,b]\;$ , and not apply the usual intermediate value theorem for continuous functions. No need of the integral mean value theorem

Comment: so based on what i did as an attempted solution is that incorrect?

Comment: @Amir I'm not even sure if what you did is wrong or not. I didn't read it all, it is too long and messy.

Comment: Ok I understand thanks for the explanation @DonAntonio